# Is there a history / eventlog in IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have a problem.
A stupid manager of one of my projects had logged on on the windows root server for a big project and add a webpage he needed in IIS.
Stupid as he is, he added not XXX.page.com for his new page, he added page.com for his new page.
He must have ignore the warning about a double-entry, which leeds to hard problems on the live-page of course.
I needed around 20 hours to find this stupid error, never had the freaking idea someone could had add a double entry for the domain!
And now he blames me with "I don't add this, it was automaticly!".

So, I hope you can help me:
Is there any kind of history / eventlog for IIS and adding a page / binding to a page, so I can tell him, that he is the idiot who causes the error and not me?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Windows to reliably provide you with a file or directory history like the ones you will see in [Wiki systems](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Page_history).

However, you might go along with hints - file and directory creation and modification times along with the "owner" of the file (who is usually the user who created the file, unless ownership was explicitly transferred after the fact) will help you deduce what might have been happened.

If you have shadow copies enabled on the volume where the IIS content is stored on, you also might look into older snapshot versions of the directory to see when the changes have been introduced.

> so I can tell him, that he is the idiot

You won't need any permission for *that*, really. And if you are the site administrator, there always be an information deficiency on your manager's side - he will have to trust your statements without a way to verify them.